# angular modal service error

Tags: angularjs, service, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have on my Single Page App 6 modals which are pretty complex. At the moment I've got them made with controllers, ui-bootstrap style but I don't think it is the best way beacuse controllers got pretty same code over and over again.

I decided to try re-write it as a service but it doesn't work and not showing any error in jsfiddle. Please help me finish of this modal service.

```
app.service('modalService', ['$modal',
    function ($modal) {

        var modalDefaults = {
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true,
            modalFade: true,
            templateUrl: '/app/partials/modal.html'
        };

        var modalOptions = {
            closeButtonText: 'Close',
            actionButtonText: 'OK',
            headerText: 'Proceed?',
            bodyText: 'Perform this action?'
        };

        this.showModal = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
            if (!customModalDefaults) customModalDefaults = {};
            customModalDefaults.backdrop = 'static';
            return this.show(customModalDefaults, customModalOptions);
        };

        this.show = function (customModalDefaults, customModalOptions) {
            //Create temp objects to work with since we're in a singleton service
            var tempModalDefaults = {};
            var tempModalOptions = {};

            //Map angular-ui modal custom defaults to modal defaults defined in service
            angular.extend(tempModalDefaults, modalDefaults, customModalDefaults);

            //Map modal.html $scope custom properties to defaults defined in service
            angular.extend(tempModalOptions, modalOptions, customModalOptions);

            if (!tempModalDefaults.controller) {
                tempModalDefaults.controller = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                    $scope.modalOptions = tempModalOptions;
                    $scope.modalOptions.ok = function (result) {
                        $modalInstance.close(result);
                    };
                    $scope.modalOptions.close = function (result) {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    };
                }
            }

            return $modal.open(tempModalDefaults).result;
        };

    }]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/3095/

Comment: $model should be $uibModal .

Comment: It doesn't fix anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `UI Bootstrap`, You need to correct below things:

1. Inject `'ui.bootstrap'` as module., like `angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);`
2. Change `$modal` to `'$uibModal'`
3. From `HTML` you need to call `controller $scope function` to show modal popup., so create method in controller.
4. Remove `$scope` from controller, it **can't be injected** to service, only passed through the function param.

Here is demo [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/3095/) of your code.

further also Read the [Doc.](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) and go through [doc plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/85KqMkMAIS1lX4WumAW8?p=preview) as well.

Comment: I dont understand trird point, can u explain some more? And your link to fiddle is same code as mine is it expected?

Comment: I've done changes 1,2 and 4 and it is still the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/8MVLJ/3115/

Comment: @BorysTymiński : remove `angularModalService` also from `angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angularModalService']);`, as I don't see this as module. Here is [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m4mutx1/)